# Page stuttering on load

Tags: pages

My [theme](http://www.elevancement.com/themes/browse/) is using `nprogress.js` and `scrollreveal.js`. When you click to a new page in the website the page shows for a split second before fading in. Its as if the page is loading ahead of my scripts, causing a very unpolished stutter in the site.

**EDIT:** Is this an enqueue issue?

**My nprogress.js script:**

```
// nprogress.js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

NProgress.start();
setTimeout(function () {
    NProgress.done();
    jQuery('.fade').removeClass('out');
}, 1000);

});
```

**My scrollreveal.js script:**

```
// scrollreveal.js
(function (jQuery) {

window.scrollReveal = new scrollReveal({
    reset: false,
    move: '50px',
    init: false
});

// Now check for new elements in the DOM…
scrollReveal.init();

})();
```

**My enqueue.php:**

```
function foundationEnqueue() {
  if (!is_admin()) {

// deregister core jquery
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
// reregister jquery 2.1.0
wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri()."/js/vendor/jquery.js", array(),'2.1.0',false);
// reregister jquery 2.1.0
wp_register_script('jquery110', "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js", array(),'1.1.0',true);
// register modernizr
wp_register_script('modernizer', get_template_directory_uri()."/js/vendor/modernizr.js",array(jquery),'2.1.0', false);
// register nprogress
wp_register_script('nprogress', get_template_directory_uri()."/js/nprogress/nprogress.js",array(jquery110),'1.1.0', true);
// register scrollreveal
wp_register_script('scrollreveal', get_template_directory_uri()."/js/scrollreveal/scrollreveal.js",array(jquery),'2.1.0', false);
// register slick
wp_register_script('slick', get_template_directory_uri()."/js/slick/slick.min.js",array(jquery),'2.1.0', false);
// register foundation.min
wp_register_script('foundation', get_template_directory_uri()."/js/foundation.min.js", array('jquery'),'2.1.0',true); 
// register foundation.theme
wp_register_script('theme', get_template_directory_uri()."/js/foundation.theme.js", array('jquery'),'2.1.0',false);
// register foundation.particles
wp_register_script('particles', get_template_directory_uri()."/js/foundation.particles.js", array('jquery'),'2.1.0',true);

wp_enqueue_script(array('jquery','jquery110','modernizer','nprogress','scrollreveal','slick','foundation','theme','particles'));

  }
}
```

The entire website is wrapped into a `.container` with the settings `data-scroll-reveal="enter from the top over 1.0s no reset" data-sr-initialized="true" data-sr-complete="true"`

Does anyone know why my site might be stuttering on load like this? I cannot find any documentation to fix it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/151794/edit) to show how you've enqueued the scripts. Glancing at your code, they appear to be in the footer, which would mean they'd load *after* your page content.

Comment: Clearly not a WordPress question...

Comment: @vancoder, clearly if you saw my [THEME](http://www.elevancement.com/themes/) you would realize this is a Wordpress site and I think it has something to do with the enqueue.

Comment: @patj, thank you for your helpful response. OP has been appended with my `enqueue` script.

Comment: Mhhh, maybe load ngprogress in the header too...

Comment: The fact that this is a WP site does not necessarily make this a WP question. Your issue is due to the JS you are using. Even if _where_ you load the JS is a factor, this still does not make it an issue specific to WordPress. This would apply to any site, WP or not.

Comment: if your javascript executes on DOM ready, it doesn't matter where you enqueue the js files, the code will always execute at the same time.

Comment: @GioiaFueter, ill look into that. Might work.

Comment: @vancoder give it a rest please. I cannot duplicate this issue on a non-wordpress site. Stop giving me, and i assume others, a difficult time. Im seeking advice on how to proceed. If you cannot assist then please answer elsewhere. If there is an issue with my code and my specific issue please, I am all ears. :)

Comment: @Milo, if that is the case then is there a way I can tell the elements to hide until nprogress finishes its animation? That might stop the stutter. Or am I misinterpreting how this works (likely)?

Comment: You could hide the content with CSS and use JavaScript to show it fist thing as it loads, that usually works for me with any kind of flicker of unstyled content...

Comment: I have no idea how the script is supposed to work, I was just basing my comment on the js code you've added. but I have to agree, the solution isn't WordPress-related, you'll probably have better luck getting an answer to this on StackOverflow.

Comment: Where do you think I originally posted this :P no one bothered. That is why I came here. It is functioning properly on my non-Wordpress test site, however when it is Wordpress it is malfunctioning. If I find a solution ill post a fix, but if its a jquery css fix then ill delete.

Comment: Have a look at [the docs for `wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) -- the first parameter, `$handle`, should be a string, not an array. I see nothing in [the source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php#L176) that would lead me to believe an array would work. (Also, why deregister WP's `jquery`?)

Comment: @PatJ the enqueue scripts do work... it is a matter of maybe initializing or placing the script in head or footer or maybe set priority, being new to wordpress I am unsure. I deregistered WP's `jquery` because im using my custom `Foundation 5.3` Wordpress framework, which requires `jquery 2.0` to run.